# Amazon Redshift: having issue at the END IF point

Tags: amazon-web-services, if-statement, amazon-redshift

Working with Amazon Redshift having issue at the END IF point:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE IF_CON()
AS $$
DECLARE
BEGIN
      IF(SELECT EXISTS(SELECT clientid FROM ods_epremis.new_old_merge)) THEN
               BEGIN
                      UPDATE ods_epremis.new_old_merge SET patientencounter_id=(SELECT max(patientencounter_id) 
                      FROM ods_epremis.new_old_merge)+1 
                      WHERE new_old_merge.clain_oid =(SELECT top 1 claim_oid from ods_epremis.new_old_merge)
                     
                      INSERT INTO ods_epremis.CLM_REM_MAPPING_PATIENT_ENCOUNTER
                      SELECT * from ods_epremis.new_old_merge
                      where claim_oid=(select top 1 claim_oid from ods_epremis.new_old_merge order by claim_oid)
               END IF
     END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: What is the _exact_ error message you are receiving?

Answer (score 1):

Your nesting is: `IF / BEGIN / END IF / END`

It should probably be: `IF / BEGIN / END / END IF`

This keeps the BEGIN/END transaction inside the IF.

Also, based on examples from [Structure of PL/pgSQL - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_PLpgSQL-structure.html), commands should end with semi-colons (`;`):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE record_example()
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
  rec RECORD;
BEGIN
  FOR rec IN SELECT a FROM tbl_record
  LOOP
    RAISE INFO 'a = %', rec.a;
  END LOOP;
END;
$$;
```